# Clicking on multiple divs but showing only one class (Angular2)?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, modal-dialog, angular2-template

I'm working on a modal window in angular and when I open the modal window and click outside that modal window (shaded background) I always get the wrong class of that div element.

Example: I click on the modal and the *modal* class appears which is OK, when I click on the shaded background the *modal* class appears again, Why? Another class should appear instead.

Here is the **code** (typescript file):

```
@ViewChild('ova') ova; //accessing the div via refference tag in html
@HostListener('document:click') onClick($event){
    if (this.show)
    console.log("display event: "+ this.ova.nativeElement.className)
```

Here is the corresponding .html file:

```
<div class="modalall">
      <div *ngIf="closeIt" (click)="close()"n class="modalclose">x</div>
      <div #ova class="modal">
         some text
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you want the class? I think when you open a modal there is a div that contains the modal inside so when you click you get that div in both times.
So perhaps you are getting the wrong class the first time and not the second

Comment: what is ths css of your modal?

Comment: to complete @Wandrille's request, could make a working plunkr ? My guess is that your z-index is messing up your clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (better in a directive):

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
```